# Why i keep getting character ' ' is an invalid XML character when there is no special character visble

Tags: java, dom, w3c

I am trying locale translation on docx file with content

```
Name
Name <emp/100>
AccProd < Tool>
Data <Cont:9000000>
ML <mail@gmail.com>
Alto <TL100>
Test<888>
Address < India>
Mode <AUTO>
Mode <manual>
```

but i don't get the proper translated file, it keeps giving this error(belo), while it doesn't state which character it is finding it invalid.

```
org.w3c.dom.DOMException: STRING_TOO_LONG: 
The resulting string is too long to fit in a DOMString: 'The character ' ' is an invalid XML character'.
Caused by: java.io.IOException: The character ' ' is an invalid XML character
```

Code :

```
DOMImplementationLS ls = (DOMImplementationLS) document.getImplementation();
LSSerializer ser = ls.createLSSerializer();
String xml = ser.writeToString(currentNode);  ------> this is where is throws exceptions
```

currentNode = node from document to be translated

Comment: Just how large is currentNode?  How many children does it have?  How much text content does it have?

Comment: My guess is that there is a [control character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_control_characters) being used that xml doesn't like.  We have seen this exact same problem with a [form feed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_break) character.

Comment: Please clarify what kind of file you want to read. A docx file is a Microsoft Word file. Do you mean you want to parse a Word file as XML?

Comment: @vanje  i am parsing docx file , internally it converts it to xml and processes it to output the final translated file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found that the issue was occuring due to multiple thread trying to access the document and serialize it and another thread using the document with incomplete xml data.
keeping the code mentioned, in description, in synchronized block worked fine with no weird exceptions.
since i am new to this, it quite learning experience. thanks all for taking time to review my problem.  @VGR @hooknc @vanje